# Efficient way to intersect multiple large files containing geodata

Tags: python, mysql, performance, hadoop, arcmap

Okay, deep breath, this may be a bit verbose, but better to err on the side of detail than lack thereof...

So, in one sentence, my goal is to find the intersection of about 22 ~300-400mb files based on 3 of 139 attributes.:

Now a bit more background. The files range from ~300-400mb, consisting of 139 columns and typically in the range of 400,000-600,000 rows. I have three particular fields I want to join on - a unique ID, and latitude/longitude (with a bit of a tolerance if possible). The goal is to determine which of these recored existed across certain ranges of files. Going worst case, that will mean performing a 22 file intersection.

So far, the following has failed

I tried using MySQL to perform the join. This was back when I was only looking at 7 years. Attempting the join on 7 years (using INNER JOIN about 7 times... e.g. t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON condition INNER JOIN t3 ON condition ... etc), I let it run for about 48 hours before the timeout ended it. Was it likely to actually still be running, or does that seem overly long? Despite all the suggestions I found to enable better multithreading and more RAM usage, I couldn't seem to get the cpu usage above 25%. If this is a good approach to pursue, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I tried using ArcMap. I converted the CSVs to tables and imported them into a file geodatabase.  I ran the intersection tool on two files, which took about 4 days, and the number of records returned was more than twice the number of input features combined. Each file had about 600,000 records. The intersection returned with 2,000,0000 results. In other cases, not all records were recognized by ArcMap. ArcMap says there are 5,000 records, when in reality there are 400,000+

I tried combining in python. Firstly, I can immediately tell RAM is going to be an issue. Each file takes up roughly 2GB of RAM in python when fully opened. I do this with:

```
f1 = [row for row in csv.reader(open('file1.csv', 'rU'))]
f2 = [row for row in csv.reader(open('file2.csv', 'rU'))]
joinOut = csv.writer(open('Intersect.csv', 'wb'))
uniqueIDs = set([row[uniqueIDIndex] for row in f1].extend([row[uniqueIDIndex] for row in f2]))
for uniqueID in uniqueIDs:
    f1rows = [row for row in f1 if row[uniqueIDIndex] == uniqueID]
    f2rows = [row for row in f2 if row[uniqueIDIndex] == uniqueID]
    if len(f1rows) == 0 or len(f2rows) == 0:
        //Not an intersect
    else:
        // Strings, split at decimal, if integer and first 3 places
        // after decimal are equal, they are spatially close enough
        f1lat = f1rows[0][latIndex].split('.')
        f1long = f1rows[0][longIndex].split('.')
        f2lat = f2rows[0][latIndex].split('.')
        f2long = f2rows[0][longIndex].split('.')
        if f1lat[0]+f1lat[1][:3] == f2lat[0]+f2lat[1][:3] and f1long[0]+f1long[1][:3] == f2long[0]+f2long[1][:3]:
            joinOut.writerows([f1rows[0], f2rows[0]])
```

Obviously, this approach requires that the files being intersected are available in memory. Well I only have 16GB of RAM available and 22 files would need ~44GB of RAM. I could change it so that instead, when each uniqueID is iterated, it opens and parses each file for the row with that uniqueID. This has the benefit of reducing the footprint to almost nothing, but with hundreds of thousands of unique IDs, that could take an unreasonable amount of time to execute.

So, here I am, asking for suggestions on how I can best handle this data. I have an i7-3770k at 4.4Ghz, 16GB RAM, and a vertex4 SSD, rated at 560 MB/s read speed. Is this machine even capable of handling this amount of data?

Another venue I've thought about exploring is an Amazon EC2 cluster and Hadoop. Would that be a better idea to investigate?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but couldn't you just pre-process all the files to extract the 3 attributes you're interested in first?  You can always keep track of the file/rownumber as well, so you can reference all the original attributes later if you want.

Comment: One of those moments where you spend days beating your head against a wall just to see a suggestion like this and think gahhh, where was that idea when I needed it? Anyway, good advice. I wrote a script to clean the files down to the three attributes, and now I'm intersecting those files. I can have all 22 open now, with some other dictionaries for quick lookups, at ~4.5GB RAM used. And at the rate it's going, seems it'll take about 7-8 hours to finish the intersect. Then I'll have to go back through the files and get the corresponding rows. Thanks again! If you answer I'll mark you accepted

Comment: We all have those moments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion:**  Pre-process all the files to extract the 3 attributes you're interested in first.  You can always keep track of the file/rownumber as well, so you can reference all the original attributes later if you want.